# Why is my pistol a grenade?

Tags: borderlands-2

When I reload my weapon, instead of simply reloading it, my character (Zero) throws it away. It either hits an enemy and does a lot of damage, or vanishes in the air.

It only seems to be happening with pistols.

Is this a class-specific ability of some kind? I'm only level 5 and haven't unlocked any other talent tree skills.

Comment: Chuck it at something flying for an achievement

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are just simply using a Tediore manufactured gun. In Borderlands 2, whenever you reload with a Tediore, your character tosses the gun away, which explodes and can do damage to enemies. Shortly thereafter, a new copy of the gun [digistructs](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Digistruct) in your hands.

Comment: Cheap mass-produced crap that explodes when you throw it away! That's Tediore! *end commercial*

Comment: There, fixed :D

Comment: I *wish* I could have thrown away all those Equilizers in Borderlands like this...

Comment: That's an awesome game mechanic!

Comment: Also beware, if you reload before the your ammo clip runs out, the gun eats up the remaining ammos as it's being tossed.

Comment: The amount of ammo left in the gun when you reload determines how much damage it does. Throwing a full gun wastes a lot of ammo, but does a ton of damage.

Answer (score 6):

As Jin said, when you reload any Tediore gun you discard the entire clip (even if it had bullets left in it).  Also note that the damage that the thrown gun does seems to be proportional to the number of bullets left in the clip that you discarded.

E.g., at lvl.12 the first Eridium gun that I got was a Thediore which would do 1000 damage if I reloaded after firing only once (36/40 clip - it used 4 ammo per shot).